# What kind of halogen bulb is this?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, ceiling-fan, bulb

One of our ceiling fan bulbs recently went out, and I can't for the life of me find a replacement for it.

By my best approximations, size is 3.65" H x 1.3" W, and 11-12mm at the base. The engraving says, "GE 120V 29W CHINA G50". The G50 part really throws me off.

[image]
[image]

[This](https://smile.amazon.com/Philips-419200-Equivalent-Candelabra-Dimmable/dp/B00TM1JFEA/?th=1) is the closest I can find, but I'm not certain it's correct.

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00IGIT02M/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_api_bfVSAbSXJSVTY

Comment: That’s a halogen lamp, and a bit odd, but see the amazon link above.

Comment: Looks like exactly what I need. Thanks @Tyson!

Comment: Looks like could be a night light base as well. If neither place you went could figure it out, then either it is an uncommon size, or they are not to "bright"!

Comment: @JeffCates the proper name for “night light base” is “candelabra base”.  This bulb looks like a common chandelier bulb at first, but if you zoom the pic it’s a bit of an oddball because it has a halogen envelope inside instead of the typical filament.

Comment: Are tungsten-halogen filaments resistant to vibration? Are they suitable for a light fixture on a fan?

Comment: they are just tungsten. ... halogen is the gas that fills the bulb ... it prevents the blackening of the glass by the deposits from evaporated tungsten

Comment: @Tyson Yes, a night light is a candelabra base, but smaller. None of my ceiling fan candelabra base bulbs will fit into my night light bases. When looking at a bulb package, you will find some that state for night light use, and some that say candelabra or even chandelier.

Comment: @JeffCates and some will say intermediate which many ceiling fans use. But pictured above is candelabra.

Comment: You could make it easier and just buy a pack of LED replacement bulbs and change them all at once or just have them for when the next one goes and replace them one by one.

Comment: There are two issues here:  do you want an exact replacement, or something that fits and is functionally the same?   The technology of the bulb pictured is a halogen capsule enveloped in a candelabra package.  Some manufacturers have started doing this for whatever reasons.  I have an exterior flood light built in a similar manner.   If you just want an light to fit, focus on the base and the lumens desired.   Hint: LEDs are cheaper energy wise.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a torpedo bulb with a candelabra base (the base indicates globe style, it's mislabeled). If the voltage is at least accurate, that 29w should be a 40W incandescent equivalent, which is how many manufacturers often indicate wattage on packaging. They also make LED versions of virtually every bulb nowadays if you wanted to get an even more energy efficient version, a decent sized hardware store might carry them.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You've really jumped in here, and with good answers, too. While you're at it, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

G50 stands for 'globe' with diameter of 50mm (or 50/8 in if you're in US) -> it should be the code for the shape (but in this case it's wrong) -> in China they have used same 'screws' for different kinds of bulbs ignoring this specific part of code. They should have used 'C' instead.

Measure the maximum diameter (instead of length), convert it to inch 1/8th and your bulb will be C diameter of bulb expressed in 1/8 (ex: C8 if the diameter is 1in)

Or: 
Just go to local hardware store and ask to the clerk with the sample.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Lowe's and Batteries Plus Bulbs had never seen this kind before.

Comment: Check also socket size, it doesn't lok like standard E14. Measure the diameter (in mm). I think in US you have thinner socket than here in EU. E11, E12 and E26 versus our E14 and E27. So 'write the full bulb code' than ask for it. Your may be a 'mini candelabra (E11) or a candelabra (E12) size. Just buy  one-per-kind and see what fits